# Kivy- make object being REPLICATED when Dragged

Tags: python, kivy

[UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJpaV.png)

As seen above picture, I want to make my apples remaining on spot, and replicated apples become draagable object. 
Which way will it be possible?

Here's my code now.

**mn.py**

```
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.behaviors import DragBehavior
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import StringProperty


class apple_0(DragBehavior,Widget):
    def on_touch_move(self,touch):
        return super(apple_0, self).on_touch_move(touch)

class apple_1(DragBehavior,Widget):
    def on_touch_move(self,touch):
        return super(apple_1, self).on_touch_move(touch)

class base_0(Widget):
    def basepicture_0(self):
        pass

class mn(Widget):
    pass

class mnApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return mn()

if __name__=='__main__':
    mnApp().run()
```

**mn.kv**

```
<mn>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: 1,1,1,1
        Rectangle:
            size: root.width,root.height
            pos: 0,0

    Label:
        pos: 30, root.top- 70
        text:
            ('[size=20][color=000000]'
            'fnc_slide_0'
            '[/color][/0ize]')
        markup: True

    base_0:
        id: base_0_id
        pos: root.width/7, root.height/3

    apple_0:
        id: apple_0_id
        pos: root.width/1.7,root.height/1.6
        auto_bring_to_front: True

    apple_1:
        id: apple_1_id
        pos: root.width/1.5,root.height/1.6
        auto_bring_to_front: True

<base_0>
    size: 944, 502
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            source: 'base_0.png'

<apple_0>:
    size: 56.25,56.25
    drag_rectangle: self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height
    drag_timeout: 10000000
    drag_distance: 0
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            source: 'apple_0.png'

<apple_1>:
    size: 28.125,56.25
    drag_rectangle: self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height
    drag_timeout: 10000000
    drag_distance: 0
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            source: 'apple_1.png'
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a new widget that will be clickable and could store an image. Use `canvas` if you want, but I did it with `Image`, then you can just pass `source` in `__init__`. Such a widget will have a function that will accept position and a class of a widget you want to spawn.

When the spawner is clicked, it creates a new instance of a widget (therefore the class in arguments) and sets its position to position of the spawner. As the widget that's on the top catches all the touches, no further `on_release` will be triggered unless you *move* the widget or click in the place that's not covered by your apple (the edges if your apple image is round).

Only edited parts of:

**.py**

```
class Spawner(ButtonBehavior, Image):
    def spawn(self, pos, widgetcls, *args):
        widget_instance = widgetcls(pos=pos)
        self.parent.add_widget(widget_instance)
```

**.kv**

```
#:import Factory kivy.factory.Factory
<mn>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: 1,1,1,1
        Rectangle:
            size: root.width,root.height
            pos: 0,0

    Label:
        pos: 30, root.top- 70
        text:
            ('[size=20][color=000000]'
            'fnc_slide_0'
            '[/color][/0ize]')
        markup: True

    base_0:
        id: base_0_id
        pos: root.width/7, root.height/3

    Spawner:
        id: apple_0_id
        pos: root.width/1.7,root.height/1.6
        on_release: self.spawn(self.pos, Factory.apple_0)

    Spawner:
        id: apple_1_id
        pos: root.width/1.5,root.height/1.6
        on_release: self.spawn(self.pos, Factory.apple_1)
```

Or do it directly in `kv`, with `self.parent.add_widget(Factory.<widget>(pos=self.pos))`, but that's less flexible.